# C++ Printing to File Not Working as Expected

Tags: c++

I tried posting this question yesterday but I did a poor job of it. I'm going to provide the complete algorithm this time and hopefully pin down an answer. I really want to be able to understand why this code is behaving the way it is. If it matters, I am on Windows 10 using VS Code.

I wrote a program for class to numerically solve the motion of a pendulum using the Explicit Euler method. I'd like to write my solution data to a text file for plotting in a separate program. The problem is that when I write my data to file it only prints up to line 341 when I expect 1001 lines.

**But** if I include the line shown below that prints all the data to screen using cout (in the Explicit Euler loop, currently commented out), then the data is entirely and correctly printed to file as I expect. Why is that the case? Why doesn't it work without having that particular line in there?

I am sure I am missing something here or there is some type of undefined behavior I am unknowingly creating. In general if anyone has any constructive suggestions on how to improve my code I'm happy to hear it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    double L = 0.6; 
    double g = 9.81; 
    double co = - g / L;  
    double dt = 1E-02; // time step [s]
    double tend = 10; // end time [s]
    double deg2rad = M_PI / 180.0; // conversion factor from deg to radian
    double tstep = tend / dt; // calculate number of time steps
    unsigned int n = static_cast<unsigned int>(tstep) + 1; // number of elements
    int Ncase = 5; // number of cases to evaluate initial value of theta
    vector<double> th0(Ncase,0.0); // vector to hold initial amplitude values to test
    vector<double> tvec(n,0.0); // vector to hold initial amplitude values to test
    vector< vector<double> > z1; // sln (theta) data for Method (1), any theta
    vector< vector<double> > w1; // sln (derivative of theta) data for Method (1), any theta
    // =====================

    // Fill in initial guesses of theta, in degrees
    th0[0] = 2.0; th0[1] = 5.0; th0[2] = 7.5; th0[3] = 10.0; th0[4] = 15.0;
    // Convert to radians
    for ( int i(0); i<Ncase; ++i ){
        th0[i] *= deg2rad;
    }

    // Pre-allocate the solution matrices
    for ( int i(0); i<Ncase; ++i){
        vector<double> tmp(n,0.0);
        w1.push_back(tmp); 
        tmp[0] = th0[i]; 
        z1.push_back(tmp);
    }

    // Create time vector
    for ( int i(0); i<n; ++i ){
        tvec[i+1] = tvec[i] + dt;
    }
    // Explicit Euler Loops
    for ( int i(0); i<Ncase; ++i){ // Case loop
        for ( int j(0); j<n; ++j){ // Time loop
            z1[i][j+1] = z1[i][j] + dt * w1[i][j]; // Solve for z, method (1)
            // cout << "Row: " << i << " Col: " << j << " w1[i][j]: " << w1[i][j] << " dt: " << dt << " z1[i][j]: " << z1[i][j] << endl; // This line makes it print to file correctly
            w1[i][j+1] = w1[i][j] + dt * ( co * sin(z1[i][j]) ); // Solve for w, method (1)
        }
    }

    // Write data to file, it is row-wise, write it as column-wise (i.e. transpose)
    ofstream sln1_data; // declare file handle    
    sln1_data.open("Sln1.dat"); // open file for w1riting
    sln1_data << "t th0 th1 th2 th3 th4" << endl; // Header line
    for ( int i(0); i<n; ++i){ // Solution column-wise into file
        sln1_data << tvec[i] << " ";
        for ( int j(0); j<Ncase; ++j){
            sln1_data << z1[j][i] << " ";
        }
        sln1_data << endl;
    }
    sln1_data.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bounds checking to your code and you'll see you access arrays out of bounds in lots of places.

```
...
// Create time vector
for ( int i(0); i<n; ++i ){

    if(tvec.size() <= (i+1))
        std::cerr << "access out of bounds in tvec loop" << std::endl;

    tvec[i+1] = tvec[i] + dt;
}
// Explicit Euler Loops
for ( int i(0); i<Ncase; ++i){ // Case loop
    for ( int j(0); j<n; ++j){ // Time loop

        if (z1.size() <= i)
            std::cerr << "access out of bounds z1" << std::endl;
        if (z1[i].size() <= (j+1))
            std::cerr << "access out of bounds z1[i]" << std::endl;
        if (w1.size() <= i)
            std::cerr << "access out of bounds w1" << std::endl;
        if (w1[i].size() <= (j+1))
            std::cerr << "access out of bounds w1[i]" << std::endl;

        z1[i][j+1] = z1[i][j] + dt * w1[i][j]; // Solve for z, method (1)
        // cout << "Row: " << i << " Col: " << j << " w1[i][j]: " << w1[i][j] << " dt: " << dt << " z1[i][j]
        w1[i][j+1] = w1[i][j] + dt * ( co * sin(z1[i][j]) ); // Solve for w, method (1)
    }
}
...
```

Output:

> access out of bounds in tvec loop
>   access out of bounds z1[i]
>   access out of bounds w1[i]
>   access out of bounds z1[i]
>   access out of bounds w1[i]
>   access out of bounds z1[i]
>   access out of bounds w1[i]
>   access out of bounds z1[i]
>   access out of bounds w1[i]
>   access out of bounds z1[i]
>   access out of bounds w1[i]
>   malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. Is there a way to enable these warnings to show by default? I seem to remember back in the day when I first started using c++ if I tried accessing an element of an array out of bounds it would give a segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm an idiot. The max loop iteration seems to be causing all the problems. I'll dig into this more later but I think I have the answer. Once I confirm everything I'll reply to my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nukesub I'd suggest using [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `operator[]` since it has bounds checking.

Comment: Does the `at` operator allow you to do multi-dimensional index? Like i do with `[i][j]`? Something like `at(0,0)`?

Comment: You would do `.at(0).at(0)`, calling `at` on the reference returned by the previous call to `at`.